# django how to make the fieldname a variable when using fieldname__contains?

Tags: python, django

```
query_dict = {'server_name': 'mysql', 'type': linux}

class ServerInfo(db.models):
    server_name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.CharField(max_length=20)

from django.db.models import Q

q = Q()

for k, v in query_dict.items():
    q.add(Q(k__icontains=v), Q.AND)
```

This can’t work,how could I replace the field name with a variable like the k above?

My english is bad ,sorry about this.

Answer (score 1):

You can build a dictionary with the `key__contains` and `value` and unpacks the contents into the `Q` object call with `**` syntax. ie,

```
>>> for k, v in query_dict.items():
...     kwargs = {f'{k}_contains': v} # or use kwargs = {'%s_contains' % k: v} if the python version less than 3.6
...     q.add(Q(**kwargs), Q.AND)
```